# Is there a way to export notes taken in Google Play books?

Tags: google-books

I have taken a series of notes in a book that I read on Google Play books. Is there a way to export these notes all together as a text document or some similar format?

Comment: They might have some kind of solution here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6006461?hl=en

Answer (score 13):

Google has changed this and now if you have Android device you can get your notes on Google Drive. Simply do this:

1. Open **Play Books** on your Android device
2. Go to **Settings**
3. **Save notes, highlights and bookmarks in Google Drive** - turn this ON

This feature is still not perfect. The biggest problem I have is that page number is not recorded properly for most books. Instead, you just have link that opens the page in Google Play Books. Meaning, it'll probably work for you personally, but sharing notes and making sense of notes on different devices is problematic.

Comment: This correctly exports the full contents of the notes. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is a long shot, but there's a [Google Books API that has functions for exporting annotations](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/books/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/books/model/Annotation.CurrentVersionRanges.html). Don't know if it works for Play Books.

Comment: Since I didn't find an easy solution for having my notes in a `json` format or similar, I've made my own: https://github.com/RayRemnant/play-book-notes-to-json.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't perfect but here is one way to do it. After doing this you will receive a zip file with your book(s) and an HTML (or JSON) file with your notes.

Follow this link to the Google Data Tools https://www.google.com/settings/takeout/downloads

Click the `Create New Archive` button
[image: foo]

Click the `Select None` button

[image: foo]

Go down to Google Play Books and flick the switch on

[image: foo]

Hit the down arrow

[image: foo]

Either download all or click on the Select Books radio (a popup will appear where you can select none again and search at the top)
After you have chosen your books, go to Next at the bottom
Pick your export options and you're good to go.

[image: foo]

Comment: The long notes this way were truncated, so cant be kept elsewhere as backup. The answer for looking the notes in google drive below works fine, and the notes are of full length in drive.

Answer (score 3):

there is no such available function at the moment. I have submitted a request already, let's see what google developers say.

Comment: Currently, it is not documented in the API official page. But I'm pretty sure there is a method, because they are using it in the Java Library https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/books/v1/java/latest/ ( see: Annotations ).

Answer (score 1):

After enabling "Save notes, highlights and bookmarks in Google Drive" on your Play Books app, you can convert your notes from `.docx` into `.json` using this code:

https://github.com/RayRemnant/play-book-notes-to-json

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: The exported notes are in `gdoc` format in my Google Drive. Do you know how to set default format as `docx` instead?

Comment: @MertNuhoglu I'm from the browser interface, drive.google.com, and when selecting the files I get the download in `docx`. 
Another way would be to actually open the file, on the upper left: File > Download > Microsoft Words (docx).
Though you'd have to do this for each individual file, not very convenient.

Answer (score -1):

It works on some books and not others apparently. I can't produce a summary/review of Guttag's book for my class.I have the print version and just bought the Playbook version.